# Mutt - run commands in background

Tags: mutt

Can Mutt commands such as "save" be done in the background to allow continued use of Mutt? (In the same way that `set sendmail_wait=-1` causes `$sendmail` to be done in the background.)

Answer (score 2):

You can start whatever bogs Mutt down, then hit CTRL-Z to get out of the app, then run the bg command to put it in the background.

Do your thing, and once Mutt is through being bogged down you can get back into it by running the fg command.

Comment: Wouldn't Screen be a better approach here ?  More control, less error prone, and no output to Stdout over the stuff in the Foreground ?

Comment: Screen would work too. The learning curve is more shallow if you just use the shell's built-in facilities. I suppose it's up to preferences.

Comment: Sorry I was unclear, see edit.

Comment: What if it turns out to be an operation that never completes?